# Alternative to SQL Server Tuning Advisor?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

Are there any other tools out there that can analyze a SQL Profiler trace file and recommend indexes?

Comment: I'm not sure if this tool is what you need but I wanted to share the tool which has similar functionalities with SQL Profiler. http://anjlab.com/en/projects/opensource/sqlprofiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend the free Qure Analyzer from DB Sophic:

http://www.dbsophic.com/qure-analyzer.html

Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry, who partners with DB Sophic on a paid version of their tools which work with our Performance Advisor product. This is not an attempt to up-sell, I am merely pointing you to a free tool that seems to meet your requirements.

You may also want to look at ClearTrace - it's not a one-for-one replacement for DTA, but it is quite useful if you're already collecting traces:

http://www.sqlmag.com/article/performance/cleartrace

Answer (score 2):

If you are running SQL 2005 or higher you can use the [Index Related DMVs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187974.aspx). You can probably search Google for a handful of scripts using them.